# Defining variables in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to substitute the value of "CCC" in "*c*" which will be written in POSCAR file. But somehow the operation is not working.
I get this error: `./script-c-b-ratio.sh: line 14: 3.24*4.78: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".24*4.78")`

The operation does work well for variable i and j. Please give some suggestions. Thanks in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 3.24 3.26
do
        mkdir 'a_'$i
        cd 'a_'$i
        for j in 4.78 4.80 4.82 4.84 4.86
                do
                mkdir 'b_'$j
                cd 'b_'$j

                for k in 70.459 72.000
                do
                CCC = "echo $'((($k)/$(($i*$j))))'"
                cp ../../POSCAR_default .
                sed 's/_a_/'$i'/g' POSCAR_default > POSCAR1
                sed 's/_b_/'$j'/g' POSCAR1 > POSCAR2
                sed 's/_c_/'CCC'/g' POSCAR2 > POSCAR
                rm POSCAR_default
                rm POSCAR1
                rm POSCAR2
                done
                cd ..
                done
cd ..
done
```

Comment: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments.

Comment: @Cyrus, this should be the answer, not a comment.

Comment: I understood bash doesn't do floating point maths operations.

Comment: By the way, you can do `rm POSCAR[12] POSCAR_default` all in one go. Also `sed -e 'operation1' -e 'operation2' -e 'operation3'` all in one go too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your script handles floating point numbers, bash does not support floating point math , you can use `bc` which is the bash calculator to achieve the floating point math

Replace the line 14 with  below code in your script and it should work

```
CCC=$(echo "scale=3;$k/($i*$j)" | bc)
```

for complete reference for `bc` command visit the page https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html